# Is jQuery.inArray broken?

Tags: jquery

This is what I get with Xubuntu, Google Chrome 18.0.1025.162 and Firefox 13.0.1. Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/g4u3D/16/).

[image]

Is jQuery.inArray broken or am I making a stupid mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `inArray()` jQuery method returns an index, just like `indexOf()`.

If you change your `if` test for the jQuery API to be just like the other one, they match.

So, **no** it's not broken :-)

Comment: Thanks! But very counter-intuitive. One would expect a library would iron out such glitches of the base language; especially so if they choose a name that suggests this: *inArray* = *Is the damn value in the damn array?*

Comment: Just noticed your last line ... Eeek! that would qualify me for the `or ...` ;-)

Comment: @MajidFouladpour I have to agree - the name "inArray" implies a "yes/no" answer